# Как изменить существующее поле в MongoDb?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

У меня есть действующая база, в одной коллекции есть поле

`connectId : {type : String, index: true, unique: true},`

Мне нужно убрать атрибут уникальности для него. Как это сделать?

`connectId : {type : String, index: true},`

Спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите в индексах коллекции, видимо вы добавили индекс, что то типа:

```
db.collection.createIndex( { "a.loc": 1 }, { unique: true } )
```

Документация вот [тут](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-unique/).
П.С. Если вы используете robo 3T как менеджер базы данных, то там можно развернуть коллекцию и отредактировать индексы.